# ExportAsFixedFormat not exporting my entire worksheet if chart was previously activated on it

Tags: excel, vba

Working on a database to keep track of inventory and create forecasts of usage and stock.

One of the features required is to export a full report as PDF. I've created a Worksheet with all the charts and information required and that is the worksheet I'm Exporting.

Another feature required is to show the charts in the userform.

This bit loads the graph into the userform. I've had to activate it, otherwise the exported file was blank. I assume this is because Excel wasn't drawing the chart as it wasn't in a visible sheet.

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("StatisticsPDF").ChartObjects(3).Activate
Set MyChart = Sheets("StatisticsPDF").ChartObjects(3).Chart
MyChart.ChartStyle = 209
Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp1.bmp"
MyChart.Export filename:=Fname, FilterName:="bmp"
MyChart.ChartStyle = 201
Me.Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
Worksheets("Main").Activate
```

This is my export as PDF bit. If I open the Workbook fresh and imediately export, it works as expected.

```
Set pdf = Worksheets("StatisticsPDF")
pdf.Visible = xlSheetVisible
fileSaveName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports\Stationary Report - " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY hhmmss")
pdf.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=fileSaveName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
pdf.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

However, if I load one of the charts into the userform, and then try to export the worksheet as PDF, the exported file only includes the chart instead of the entire worksheet. I have tried Activating the worksheet first but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Excel will only print (or export) the chart if it is selected. Selecting a cell before the export command has done the trick.